# Marginal effects of a smooth in a gamm4 model

Tags: regression, generalized-additive-model, marginal-effect

I'm trying to obtain marginal effects of a smooth in a {gamm4} model. I notice a discrepancy between what {ggeffects} gives me and what I get manually.

For a smooth x0, I calcualte the predictions over a grid of x0, at the average of other two smooths, and at each level of a categorical variable. Once I have the predictions, I average over the grouping factor to obtain the marginal effects.

What is the correct way to get marginal smooths in such a case?

```r
## Logistic Regression with smooth and categorical variables   

### Simulate some data   

# Scale the variables to mean 0 and variance 1 

# Create an 'id' variable, that is the repeat measurments for each subject

library(tidyverse)
library(gamm4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'Matrix'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     expand
#> Loading required package: lme4
#> Loading required package: mgcv
#> Loading required package: nlme
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'nlme'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:lme4':
#> 
#>     lmList
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     collapse
#> This is mgcv 1.8-28. For overview type 'help("mgcv-package")'.
#> This is gamm4 0.2-5
library(ggeffects)
set.seed(1252)

df <- gamSim(eg = 4, n = 400)
#> Factor `by' variable example
df <- df %>%
  mutate(id = rep(c("1","2","3","4","5"), each = 80 )) %>%
  mutate(x0 = scale(x0),
         x1 = scale(x1),
         x2 = scale(x2),
         y = rbinom(400,1,0.8),
         fac2 = map_chr(1:400, ~sample(1:3, 1, replace = TRUE)))


### Model  

df_gam <- gamm4::gamm4(y ~ s(x0) + s(x1) + s(x2)+ fac + fac2, random = ~ (1|id), data = df, family = binomial(link = "logit"))


### ggeffects predict method  

ggpredict(df_gam, "x0") %>% plot()
#> Warning in model.frame.default(Terms[[i]], data, xlev = object$xlevels):
#> variable 'fac2' is not a factor
#> Error: variable 'fac2' was fitted with type "character" but type "numeric" was supplied


### manually  

## Create a grid of `x0` values at the average value of x1 and x2 at each level of the categorical variable.  

## Make predictions on this and average over the categorical variable `fac` to get the mean prediction and the associated interval   

grid <- expand.grid(x0 = seq(-2,2 ,by = 0.01), x1 = 0, x2 = 0, fac = c("1","2","3"), fac2 = c("1","2","3"))

x0_preds <- predict.gam(df_gam$gam, newdata = grid, type = "response", se.fit = TRUE)
pred_df <- cbind(grid, as.data.frame(x0_preds))

pred_df %>%
  group_by(x0) %>%
  mutate(fit = mean(fit)) %>%
  mutate(lower = fit - 2*se.fit, upper = fit + 2*se.fit) %>%
  summarize(fit = mean(fit), lower = mean(lower), upper = mean(upper)) %>% ## by grouping x0, average over the levels of fac
  ggplot(.,aes(x0, fit)) + geom_line() + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper), alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

```r
sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
#> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#>  [1] ggeffects_0.12.0 gamm4_0.2-5      mgcv_1.8-28      nlme_3.1-140    
#>  [5] lme4_1.1-21      Matrix_1.2-17    forcats_0.4.0    stringr_1.4.0   
#>  [9] dplyr_0.8.3      purrr_0.3.2      readr_1.3.1      tidyr_0.8.3     
#> [13] tibble_2.1.3     ggplot2_3.2.0    tidyverse_1.2.1 
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] sjlabelled_1.1.0 tidyselect_0.2.5 xfun_0.8         splines_3.6.1   
#>  [5] haven_2.1.1      lattice_0.20-38  colorspace_1.4-1 generics_0.0.2  
#>  [9] vctrs_0.2.0      htmltools_0.3.6  yaml_2.2.0       rlang_0.4.0     
#> [13] nloptr_1.2.1     pillar_1.4.2     glue_1.3.1       withr_2.1.2     
#> [17] modelr_0.1.4     readxl_1.3.1     sjmisc_2.8.1     munsell_0.5.0   
#> [21] gtable_0.3.0     cellranger_1.1.0 rvest_0.3.4      evaluate_0.14   
#> [25] labeling_0.3     knitr_1.23       highr_0.8        broom_0.5.2     
#> [29] Rcpp_1.0.1       scales_1.0.0     backports_1.1.4  jsonlite_1.6    
#> [33] hms_0.5.0        digest_0.6.20    stringi_1.4.3    insight_0.5.0   
#> [37] grid_3.6.1       cli_1.1.0        tools_3.6.1      magrittr_1.5    
#> [41] lazyeval_0.2.2   crayon_1.3.4     pkgconfig_2.0.2  zeallot_0.1.0   
#> [45] MASS_7.3-51.4    xml2_1.2.0       lubridate_1.7.4  minqa_1.2.4     
#> [49] assertthat_0.2.1 rmarkdown_1.14   httr_1.4.0       R6_2.4.0        
#> [53] boot_1.3-22      compiler_3.6.1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: What makes marginalized effects be of interest?  Those will be functions of the (often arbitrary) distribution you are marginalizing over.  Conditional distributions are more often of interest.

Answer (score 0):

The reprex made things clear.  Earlier I was including the factor in the `by` statement in the `s(x0, by = fac)`.  I think that was causing problems.